# C++ stof function cast to integer

Tags: c++, string, casting, int

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{ 
    int val = std::stof("4.99") * 100; 

    std::cout << val; 

    return 0; 
}
```

I've tried other strings and they all seem to be converting correctly, but I am not sure what is happening behind the scenes that is causing this to output `498` instead of `499`. In my use case, every string has a maximum of `2` decimal places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *nearest* IEEE754 `float` to `4.99` is `4.9899997711181640625`. `std::stof` will return the latter.

That multiplied by `100` is `498.999969482421875` which is truncated to `498`.

This is one of the pitfalls of floating point arithmetic I'm afraid; you need to take a lot of care when using a discontinuous function like a conversion of `float` to `int`; using `std::lround` on the result would work in your particular case.

Further reading: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper function that will round your floating point number properly:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{ 
    auto val = std::lround(std::stof("4.99") * 100);

    std::cout << val; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yup. Nicked that from your comment. Upvoted for larceny.

Comment: No pb at all ;)